# How to add title in header title in tab navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi I want some thing like this

```
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
||                                ||
||            header.             ||
||                                ||
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|        tab navigations           |
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

I already got the tab navigation, Here is the code how I create tab navigation

**app.js**

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Tabs />
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

**Tabs.js**

In side this component I already tried to add header navigation but nothing shows up.
I leave a comment on where I try to add header.

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const Tabs = () => {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            tabBarOptions={{
                showLabel: false,
                style: styles.tabBarOptionsStyle,
            }}
        >
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={HomeScreen}
                options={{
                    //NOT WORKING
                    title: 'Home',
                    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
                        <View style={styles.tabIconPosition}>
                            <Image
                                style={[
                                    styles.iconArea,
                                    focused ? styles.focusTint : styles.unFocusTint,
                                ]}
                                source={require("../assets/Icons/home.png")}
                            ></Image>
                            <Text
                                style={[
                                    styles.tabTextSize,
                                    focused ? styles.focusColor : styles.unFocusColor,
                                ]}
                            >
                                Home
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    ),
                }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Cart"
                component={CartScreen}
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
                        <View style={styles.tabIconPosition}>
                            <Image
                                style={[
                                    styles.iconArea,
                                    focused ? styles.focusTint : styles.unFocusTint,
                                ]}
                                source={require("../assets/Icons/bag.png")}
                            ></Image>
                            <Text
                                style={[
                                    styles.tabTextSize,
                                    focused ? styles.focusColor : styles.unFocusColor,
                                ]}
                            >
                                Shop
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    ),
                }}
            />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
};
```

I try to read the react document and add `title: 'Home',` in the navigation but nothing shows up. Can some one help

Answer (score 0):

We can place the tab navigator inside the stack navigation so it will come with a stack header.

for ex.

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const Tabs = () => {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            tabBarOptions={{
                showLabel: false,
                style: styles.tabBarOptionsStyle,
            }}
        >
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={HomeScreen}
            />
        </Tab.Navigator>
     )
}

const MainNavigation = () => {
    return (
        <Stack.Screen
            name="Main"
            component={Tabs}
        />
    )

}
```